# RewriteRule don't work in htacces and I get 404 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

### PRODUCCION
RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contacto.html$ contacto.php [L]
RewriteRule ^mapa-de-sitio.html$ mapa-de-sitio.php [L]
RewriteRule ^delivery/(.+).html$ avisos.php?rubro=$1&delivery=1 [R]
RewriteRule ^delivery.html$ delivery.php [L]
RewriteRule ^planos.html$ planos.php [L]
RewriteRule ^publicar-aviso.html$ publicar_aviso.php [L]
RewriteRule ^avisos.html$ avisos.php [L]

######   Rubros por letras
RewriteRule ^profesionales/([a-z]{1}).html$ rubros.php?seccion=2&letra=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^comercios/([a-z]{1}).html$ rubros.php?seccion=1&letra=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{1}).html$ rubros.php?letra=$1 [L,NC]

######   Rubros secciones generales
RewriteRule ^profesionales.html$ rubros.php?seccion=2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^comercios.html$ rubros.php?seccion=1 [L,NC]

######   Avisos
RewriteRule ^comercios/(.+).html$ avisos.php?seccion=1&rubro=$1 
RewriteRule ^profesionales/(.+).html$ avisos.php?seccion=2&rubro=$1


######   Centros comerciales
RewriteRule ^centros-comerciales/(.+).html$ centros_comerciales.php?centro_comercial=$1

######   Instituciones
RewriteRule ^instituciones/(.+).html instituciones.php?grupo=$1
```

When  I access to http://www.test.com/delivery/books.html the browser shows me a 404 error page, where may be the problem? thanks

Comment: Is that your entire .htaccess file? The rewrite seems to work properly here. Try to add `[R]` behind the `RewriteRule ^delivery/(.+).html$ avisos.php?rubro=$1&delivery=1` (as such: `RewriteRule ^delivery/(.+).html$ avisos.php?rubro=$1&delivery=1 [R]` rule and see where you're redirected.

Comment: I paste the entire htacces now. I add [R] but still not working.

Comment: Does the same problem persist? Are you *shown* the front page (while still maintaining the URL) or are you *redirected* to http://www.test.com or are you *redirected* to avisos.php?

Answer (score 0):

After various consulted, it appears that there was a conflict with reserved words as delivery, adding `options -multiviews` at the beginning of the file, fix the problem.